# Delete and upload files into Azure webapp local storage programatically

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed a website into Azure and i want to access programaticaly this path : "D:\home\site\app" from a c# desktop application and delete all files and upload new ones programatically.
i have searched and found many ways but all are for `AzureStorage` or using `Kudu consol` or `FTP` while what i realy want is to access the local storage where the website is deployed programatiacally, and make some edits on files programatically.

Comment: Not sure what your question is, since you can access a Web App's local storage with standard I/O libraries. Azure Storage is something different (blobs/etc) which does require API/SDK usage, but... not Web App local storage.

Comment: yes, you are Right, actually what i want exactly is after deploying a web app i execute some code independently of the web application and it gonna delete all the files in app data folder and upload new ones.

Answer (score 3):

Sure thing, the Site Control Manager (Kudu) has an API for that, the VFS API:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs

You can use either of these for authentication:

- A `Bearer` token that you obtain from the STS (reference implementation in [ARMClient](https://github.com/projectkudu/ARMClient))
- Site-level credentials (the long ugly ones under your *Web App → Properties*)
- Git/FTP credentials (subscription level)

Sample usage (using site-level credentials):

[image: Kudu DebugConsole]

```
# Line breaks brutally used to improve readability
# /api/vfs/ is d:\home
# Append path as necessary, i.e. /api/vfs/site/app

$ curl -k https://$are-we-eating-too-much-garlic-as-a-people:6sujXXX
      XXXXXXq7Zc@are-we-eating-too-much-garlic-as-a-people.scm.azurewebsites.net
      /api/vfs/site/wwwroot/ill-grab-this-file-over-vfs-api.txt

There, i did it.
```

I'm assuming here that you want to do all that from the outside world - since you don't clearly state otherwise.

Comment: Yes this is what i need, but i need to code in c#, and i've searched for an example or small tuto in the web and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my azure code. my task was to save a excel file and upload its contents to SQL server.
I used this plain and simple to access home site.

```
string fileToSave = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\Temp"), FileUpload.FileName);

            if (!Directory.Exists(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\Temp")))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\Temp"));

 FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileToSave);
```

you could use something like this to delete and save a new file or other I/O operations.

Comment: Yes sure it works but not in my case because i use an other application (desktop application) to acces the first one that i deploy on azure webApp and get to the appdata Folder to make the edits